# Mongoose passing coordinates to find() method for geospartial search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a list of locations with a field "location" that has coordinates. I am trying to use the $near operator to query all locations within a specified distance from the given coordinates.

I want users to pass their own coordinates on the frontend.
This is my code

```
const lon = req.params.lon;
const lat = req.params.lat;
const shops = await Shop.find({
  location: {
    $near: {
      $maxDistance: 1000,
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [lon, lat],
      },
    },
  },
});

return res.status(200).json({
  success: true,
  data: shops,
});
```

When I try passing the latitude and longitude through params on the URL, I get nothing, is there another way I can use to pass the coordinates to the request?

My URL was something like this: "localhost:5000/api/shops/lat/lon"

Where lat is the latitude, and on is the longitude coordinates.

Comment: where is the `app.get("/api/shops ..., ..."` part of you code?

Comment: I created a controller to handle the request, then I passed the controller to the router, the router looks like this:

router.post("/api/shops/:lat/:lon", findShops)

Comment: How do I pass the coordinates to be used with $geoNear, since req.params.lat & req.params.lon is not working?

Comment: according to the mongodb documentation the query seems all right: ```{
   <location field>: {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
       },
       $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
       $minDistance: <distance in meters>
     }
   }
}``` do you have location in the Shop collection around 1000 meters from the input lat, lon ? could it be an issue using longitude instead of latitude ?

Comment: did you check with `console.log(lat, lon)` if its not undefined? and if its in the correct type? (string, number etc..)

Comment: It's returning undefined

Comment: Why are you using a POST request if you pass the parameters in the URL? Either use a GET request for that, or use a POST and pass the data as JSON in the request body, without parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: Don't forget to add ':' before the params in your url as mentioned:
api/:lon/:lat**

As you have correctly defined your query, your problem might lie in the schema definition.
Try casting to a 2D Sphere, and double check you are getting the params correctly and the distance matches your document.

```
const schema = new Schema({Your schema})
// CAST TO 2D SPHERE
schema.index({location: "2dsphere"});
```